# TemplateDoesNotExist (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to load a register template for my first django site,
I put register.html file in /home/Desktop/projects/purple/purple/templates/registration.html
here but there is a error that is say to there is no file I did not understant that's why? can anyone have a idea?

> Request Method:    GET
>
> Request URL:   http...:127.0.0.1:8000/registration/
>
> Django Version:    1.4
>
> Exception Type:    TemplateDoesNotExist
>
> Exception Value: registration.html

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

- Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:

  - /home/Desktop/projects/purple/purple/templates/registration.html (File does not exist)
- Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:

  - /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/registration.html (File does not exist)
  - /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration.html (File does not exist)
- Using loader django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader:

Comment: So is the file in /home/Desktop/projects/purple/purple/templates/ named "register.html" or "registration.html"?

Comment: Go to the directory, and see if the file exists. `cd /home/Desktop/projects/purple/purple/templates/`

Comment: I can saw with cd in terminal file is exist

Comment: I can't tell you for sure, since i'm a rookie o Django, but don't you need to insert the templates directory on TEMPLATE_DIRS on settings.py configuration file?

Answer (score 2):

Given that the exception copy and pasted refers to:

`/home/Desktop/projects/purple/purple/templates/registration.html`

and can't find it... all of your problems lie in whether or not `registration.html` exists at the directory.

There are 2 possibilities:

1. **File doesn't exist**
   cd into that exact directory and find out if it does.
2. **Permissions**
   `ls -lh /home/Desktop/projects/purple/purple/templates/registration.html`

Make sure it's readable.

```
chmod 644 /home/Desktop/projects/purple/purple/templates/registration.html
```

Comment: I checked it is readable and I found out it in exact directory, but still it is give same error

Comment: Can you show output of `ls -l`? Do any other templates load, ever? Admin site, anything.

Comment: output---> "-rw-r--r-- 1 ulascan ulascan 304 Dec  9 22:37 registration.html" I have admin templates but it is default admin directory it is also work but I am not sure which template work there exist templates/admin directory but default one can work in django files.

Comment: I want to put registration.html template into /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/ but system is not allow this permission denied error, is there a way to put it there and do you think this can solve the problem?

Comment: no - django is clearly trying to load a specific file which exists. Perhaps the app doesn't have permission (running as a different user). Just for kicks, can you try chmod 777 on the registration.html file?

Comment: I tried but nothing changed :( I think there is a very big mistake in my design ... For example I delete my template directory than admin panel can still work, and when I tried to open registration page program give same error... it did not said there is no templates diroctory, it said I looked template directory and registration.html doesnot exist...

Answer (score 0):

do you have Registration directory inside Template directory??

if so then include this is your settings.py .

```html
 TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
      BASE_DIR +'/Templates',
      BASE_DIR +'/registration',

  )
```

Because django is looking for registration.html in your Template directory instead of /template/registration.

see the order you mentioned in the question. watch the path.