# TemplateDoesNotExist on Django 3.2.2

Tags: python, django, django-3.2

I am getting the below error when, I am trying to add new application:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /listings/
listings/listings.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/listings/
Django Version: 3.2.2
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
listings/listings.html
Exception Location: /home/brup/Desktop/Python/Django/FullWebApplication/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Python Executable:  /home/brup/Desktop/Python/Django/FullWebApplication/btre_project/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.9
Python Path:    
['/home/brup/Desktop/Python/Django/FullWebApplication/btre_project',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/brup/Desktop/Python/Django/FullWebApplication/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

Note: I have gone through these links but its not helping me, I have checked these. I have added pages application and its working fine, but when I am trying to added listing application its not working.

[Solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790781/templatedoesnotexist-django) [Solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473369/templatedoesnotexist-django) [Solution3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558746/templatedoesnotexist-django)

```
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

Inside Installed Apps, I have done the the following:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
        'listings.apps.ListingsConfig',
        'realtors.apps.RealtorsConfig',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]
```

In urls.py I have added the following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('listings/', include('listings.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Listing Application:

[image]

Configuring urls.py  in listing

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='listings'),
    path('<int:listing_id>', views.listing, name='listing'),
    path('search', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

configuring views

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
  return render(request, 'listings/listings.html')

def listing(request, listing_id):
    return render(request, 'listings/listing.html')

def search(request):
  return render(request, 'listings/search.html')
```

Inside Templates folder

[image]

Comment: It is with a capital `L`, so the templates should be `Listings/listing.html`, or you use lowercase for the `Listings` directory.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have renamed the directory from Listings to listing. I am still getting the same error. But,  rest of the things seems fine to me..But this be referenced at any other place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you created listings with capital L.but you use small l in views.py.

Comment: One should generally refrain from answering questions that are caused by typographical errors as they are not very useful. You should instead leave a comment and optionally flag / vote to close the question.

Comment: i did not know.ok,thanks.

Comment: @arezoo, I have renamed the directory from Listings to listing. I am still getting the same error. But,  rest of the things seems fine to me.. not sure why this is still happening.

Comment: @arezoo Another issue was the html file name its listings..html instead it  should be lisitngs.html